# Google Analytics & tracking protection in Firefox

Tags: firefox, google-analytics, static-site

I've made static site recently and added Google Analytics script to track trafiic. However I have error in Firefox console that states:

> The resource at "https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js" was
>   blocked because tracking protection is enabled.

I understand that this is due to browser's settings, but on other websites which I browse on the same browser this error doesn't occur (mainly CMS: Wordpress, Joomla). Why? Is there a way to track data on static site when tracking protection is enabled?

Comment: Is your site built with a specific CMS? Where is it hosted?

Comment: It's a static site, pure HTML & CSS with some JS

Comment: Try to check this link: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/save-your-analytics-from-content-blockers-7ee08c6ec7ee